# Permission denied when sharing image through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to share an image from within an app's .apk (in res/drawable) using an `Intent`. Following the developer.android.com documentation ([[1]](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html), [[2]](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html), [[3]](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)), I assumed I needed to do the following:

1. Get the image from res/drawable as a `Bitmap` and save it in the app's internal storage,
2. Using a `FileProvider`, get the content uri for the image,
3. Create an `Intent` with `ACTION_SEND` action and add the uri as a stream
4. Add `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag to the intent

In practice, I just created the default "Hello World" app, replaced the text view in the main activity by a button that triggers the image sharing, and tried to share the standard ic_launcher.png image from res/drawable.

Everything runs fine until I select the other app to share the image with in the chooser dialog. No matter what I select (Adobe Reader, Facebook, MMS), the app receiving the image crashes and reports the following errors in their logs:

```
06-01 02:06:53.863: W/ActivityManager(356): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10099
06-01 02:06:53.953: E/AndroidRuntime(21961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adobe.reader/com.adobe.reader.services.cpdf.ARCreatePDFActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Using the Android Debug Monitor I can see that the image file was created in the app's internal storage with `rw` permissions for the owner, no permissions for others.

**UPDATE**
I finally had time to test this more thoroughly on a phone (4.3) and tablet (4.2). At both devices I got the exact same results. The "Permission Denied" warning is always seen in the log, but the end result may differ per app:

- Standard Android email app - email is sent without errors/crashes but
  does *not* contain the attachment,
- Gmail app - email is sent *with*
  attachment (this is the only case where I found the above code
  works),
- Facebook, Twitter, Adobe Reader - these all crash at the
  moment of selection in the chooser dialog;

Does this mean that there's no "standard" way of sharing a (image) resource from within an app's internal storage, and the sharing logic needs to be customized depending on the receiving app?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.imagesharetest.share" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.imagesharetest.share.SharingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.imagesharetest.share.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

res/filepaths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="shareImages"
        path="images/" />
</paths>
```

activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="shareImage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity .java:

```
package com.imagesharetest.share;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class SharingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sharing);
    }

    public void shareImage(View v) {
        Uri icLauncherFileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                SharingActivity.this, "com.imagesharetest.share.fileprovider",
                getICLauncherBitmapAsInternalFile());

        Intent shareIntent = getShareIntentFor(icLauncherFileURI);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Sending ic_launcher..."));
    }

    private File getICLauncherBitmapAsInternalFile() {
        Bitmap icLauncherBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
        imagePath.mkdirs();
        File icLauncherFile = new File(imagePath, "shared_image.png");
        saveBitmapAsFile(icLauncherBitmap, icLauncherFile);

        return icLauncherFile;
    }

    private void saveBitmapAsFile(Bitmap bmp, File file) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
//            FileOutputStream fos = SharingActivity.this.openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Intent getShareIntentFor(Uri contentUri) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/png");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        return shareIntent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should check once more that Uri is either correct or null??

Comment: I've tried your exact same code and it's working with no problems. Strange.

Comment: @Pankaj: E.g. the MMS app receives the following Uri: `06-01 14:56:35.795: V/Mms/image(15411): initFromContentUri: content://com.imagesharetest.share.fileprovider/shareImages/shared_image.png, getType => image/png`

Comment: Not for sharing a file from the app's internal storage. I worked around the issue by saving the image to _external_ storage (SD card). Sharing that (external) URI did work as expected.